# When you gotta go…

Tags: word-choice

Which is better?  Or is it regional?

- 请问，洗手间在哪里？
- 请问，厕所在哪里？
- 对不起，浴室在哪里？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for 洗手间 (washroom) is more subtle (imply you might just want to wash your hands)

Asking for 厕所 (toilet) is very straight forward (clearly indicate you need to perform a bodily function)

Both 洗手间 and 厕所 are acceptable, but saying 洗手间 is considered more polite.

浴室 (the bath or shower) is not a correct term

Comment: 谢谢  My teacher used 请问，厕所在哪里？, but a youtube lesson used 请问，洗手间在哪里？ Google Translate put in the 洗手间.

Comment: Sometimes, it's awkward to say 厕所在哪里？, especially in a restaurant. 洗手间 sounds like bathroom or restroom in English. 99% of time, I say 洗手间.

Comment: @伟思礼 I use 洗手间 when I am in a building, 厕所 when I am outside.